# Cannot remove DOM Element (JavaScript, CreateJS)

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs, createjs

I have a problem removing a DOMElement from the stage.
This is how I created my domElement with createjs Framework.

```
this.domElement = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById('nickname'));
    this.domElement.x = 580;
    this.domElement.y = 200;
    this.stage.addChild(this.domElement);
```

My HTMl code looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" style="visibility: hidden">
<input id="nickname" value="" size="10">
```

Everything works fine till I want to remove "domElement" from the stage.
Here is how I attempted it:

```
this.stage.removeChild(this.domElement);
```

I also tried other solutions like :

```
this.stage.parentNode.removeChild(this.domElement);
```

Do you have an ideea why I am not able to remove this DOM Element?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is `this.stage`? Have you tried to remove `this.domElement.htmlElement`? - [.htmlElement](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DOMElement.html#property_htmlElement)

Comment: "this.stage" I have created with createjs like this:
this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);

Comment: Hi Andreas, I tried your solution and I still can not remove it.
The compiler throws no error but the DOMElement is still on the stage.

Comment: Hi Andreas, i think that it is not possible to remove the htmlElement from the HTML-page. 
In my example I created a DOMElement from an htmlElement and than I positioned this DOMElement over the stage / canvas but it was not painted on the canvas. So if I delete the DOMElement the htmlElement will still be there.
I only manged to get rid of it by changing it's coordinates positioning it out of the canvas.
Thank you for trying to help me.
Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, but I got confused with createJS. Sadly I can't help you with it...

Comment: I think "removing" the Dom-Element from the stage will only "detatch" it, but since it is an HTML element it will still be visible - so you would have to make it invisible or remove it "by hand" - utilizing the createjs for DOMElements is usually only used to position the elements based on the stage-koordinates, however they are rendered separately.

Comment: I have to use a DOMElement with createjs because I need the user / player to create a username. The only way to get the username and to save it is by creating a DOMElement from an HTMLElement with createjs.
And as @olsn said, it will still be visible so I came with the idea to position the DOMElement above the canvas / stage so the player can not see it anymore.
If you know other possibility how to do this please let me know.
The solution I use now works fine but it is not the way I wanted it to be.
Thank you for writing back Andreas and olsn !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the DOMElement from the Stage will not affect the related html element it wraps. DOMElement is useful for controlling position, transformation, and visibility of an HTML element, but if you remove it from the stage, the html element is not affected, since the element is never really on the stage in the first place.

You will have to manually remove the html element from the browser DOM. Note that the stage is not an HTML element, so it does not have a "parentNode". Instead, something like this might work:

```
domElement.htmlElement.parentNode.removeChild(domElement.htmlElement);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Lany, thank you for answering. Yes you are right about removing the DOMElement from the stage has no effect on the HTMLElement, it will still be there. That is why I change the coordinates of the DOM Element and moved it away from the stage. This is the only possibility to "get rid" of it.
I tried your solution but my compiler throws me an error:
"Value not an object";

Comment: Did you add the 'this' keyword?

Answer (score 1):

@Lanny's solution to remove the element from the DOM does work. However, if you wish to use this DOM element again, then it will be gone. Therefore, I have found making the element hidden is a better solution, in my case anyway.

```
domElement.htmlElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

If you no longer have a reference to the createjs DOMElement, then you can access it this way:

```
document.getElementById("_id_").style.visibility = "hidden";
```